# How to include \index{} in new command (custom macro)?

Tags: macros, indexing

When I try to used `\index{}` inside of `\newcommand`, the entry is made in the index, however, the text no longer appears in the body. How can I achieve a macro for the `\index` command?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\newcommand{\myentry}[1]{This is an #1}

\begin{document}
\myentry{Apple}

\end{document}
```

typesets:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\newcommand{\myentry}[1]{This is an \index{#1}}

\begin{document}
\myentry{Apple}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

typesets:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `\index` merely passes information to be indexed and actually does not print anything, use

```
\newcommand{\md}[1]{This is an \index{#1}#1}
```

which prints the command after passing it to `\index`.